# jQuery .text() returns NaN, why is that?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('span#pricetotal').text(function() {
    var val = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        val += parseInt($('span#itemtotal_' + i).text());
    };
    return val;
});
```

I have 15x `<span>` where I put a price with jQuery `text()` function. In the code above I want to count a sum of them all and put it into `span#pricetotal`.

What happens however is that instead of addition `(20+20=40)`, the element shows `2020`. In the code above I used `parseInt` - this returns `NaN`.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Edit: HTML of the element looks like this:

```
<span id="itemtotal_0">16</span>
```

Comment: Showing your HTML is important for this type of question.

Comment: Most likely `parseInt($('span#itemtotal_' + i).text())` is returning NAN at some point.

Comment: parseInt is unable to parse the value returned by $('span#itemtotal_' + i).text() as an integer.  What are the values?

Comment: You've likely got a currency character in there, although the best anyone can do is guess. Can you provide a sample of the HTML?

Comment: for instance, parseInt('') is NaN.

Comment: Use parseInt() to 20+20=40

Comment: somewhere you are mixing values

Comment: At least one of the fifteen values is not a number.

Comment: Basic debugging for this type of thing would be to add `console.log( $('span#itemtotal_' + i).text() ); console.log( parseInt($('span#itemtotal_' + i).text()) );` in the loop and see what it looks like.

Comment: ^^ (or use one of the easy-to-use debuggers that are built into every browser)

Comment: If you want to allow empty input to be considered as 0 use `val += parseInt($('span#itemtotal_' + i).text()) || 0;`

Comment: `parseInt('$123') -> NaN`

Comment: Try `val += parseInt($('span#itemtotal_' + i).text()) || 0;`, then anything evaluating to NaN will be added in as zero.

Comment: Please show a complete example that shows the problem. `parseInt("16")` is *not* `NaN`.

Comment: Can you post all 15 spans?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions people, you write faster than me, so I didn't even get to respond quickly enough. I chose the answer that eventually helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#pricetotal').text(function() {
    var val = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {        
        var value = $.trim($('span#itemtotal_' + i).text());
        val +=parseInt( $.isNumeric(value) ? value : 0);
    };
    return val;
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jDnVy/6/)***

**NOTE:**

This is safe if your span contains any `space` or `non-numeric` data. In demo you will find one `span` has letter `a`.

Comment: This one does the trick, but I really don't see any white spaces in my previous code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

use condition to check..

try this

```
$('span#pricetotal').text(function() {
  var val = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      if($('span#itemtotal_' + i).text() != ""){  // <-- check if not empty since empty gives Nan when used pareseInt
        val += parseInt($('span#itemtotal_' + i).text());

      }
   };
 return val;
});
```

OR

```
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    val += parseInt($('span#itemtotal_' + i).text()) || 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly:
http://jsfiddle.net/jDnVy/5/

```
$('span#pricetotal').text(function() {
    var val = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {        
        val +=parseInt($('span#itemtotal_' + i).text());

    };
    return val;
});
```

Please, check that your itemtotal spans starts with `itemtotal_0`, not `itemtotal_1`

May be it try to find `span#itemtotal_0`, but it does not exists. Please, double check.